# How to go live with Paypal

Tags: ios, paypal

I have solved the PayPal in sandbox.But it is not changing in the LIVE mode. I have changed the sandbox APP ID and CLIENT ID into LIVE. BUt I am getting the environment-mock in the response. Can anyone help me how i can solve it.

i have set the enviroment-> self.environment=PayPalEnvironmentProduction;

```
mean ->
{

 client =   
 {

    environment = mock;
    "Paypal" = "2.0.1";
    platform = iOS;
    "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
};
response =     {
    "create_time" = "2014-03-25T10:44:43Z";
    id = "PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y";
    intent = sale;
    state = approved;
};
"response_type" = payment;
}
```

Please tell me why the environment is not changing into live from mock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change environment from `PayPalEnvironmentSandbox` to `PayPalEnvironmentProduction` and than try again. You also need to change your ClientID with live. Sandbox ClientID and live ClientID are different.

```
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentSandbox]; // Sandbox mode

[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction]; // Live mode
```

**Note**: For **live mode**, You need **real paypal account** for do transaction

For get **Sandbox ClientID** and **live ClientID**, check below snap shot,

[image: image 1]

[image]

For more reference, please go through [PayPal iOS SDK README](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: I want to ask one more thing, Is there any difference between APP Id and client id.

Comment: @user3387839 If you check paypal develoepr account than there is only Client ID and you need to replace that with LIVE client id and above environment change when you want to go live

Comment: Thankyou sir,but i want to know that client id or app id is same or not.?

Comment: @user3387839 : it is not same.. Can you please tell where is APP ID mentioned in paypal developer account?

Comment: One more thing ,Is signature and Live client-id is 
same thing???

Comment: Its different. And in apps section of paypal account, ther is option of getting live client id just below of sandbox details

Comment: sir there is REST API credintials.Is that workable in LIVE environment?

Comment: In REST API credintials, there is `Test credentials` and `Live credentials`. Please check my edited answer with snapshot

Comment: i have used the same,but in the response environment =mock,,And what is the use of EndPoint,which we got in credential.

Comment: And not all feature are available for Live,how we can enable that feature.

Comment: I have not mention the APP-ID in the paypal developer account ,can you tell me where i need to mentioned?????

Comment: I think there is nothing like APP-ID in paypal. There is ClientID only

Comment: but we got the APP ID from the Paypal,when i register our app on the Paypal - https://apps.paypal.com/user/my-account/applications/new  And  i thing it is neccesery to use ,but don't know correctly where i will use ?.

Comment: I think that is use in MPL. That is another way to implement paypal. (Older Version)

Comment: Please check this https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/

Comment: ok,then only client-id and  environment is necessary thing ?

Comment: If you are using latest sdk than yes.. i think so

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK  i am using this.,Is it latest?

Comment: Yes mat. that is latest one

Comment: now the app is crashing  when go in view will appear-[PayPalMobile preconnectWithEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork];

Comment: i think the reason of error is that ,i am not using endpoint ,what you say is it necessary to use endpoint or not ,and if yes then where i can use that ?

Comment: I am not sure about it. I had followed their instruction and works fine to me

Comment: Thank you very much sir ,i competed

Comment: omg, thats where they hide the live client id!